# Index Section in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have UITableView header custom like Instagram where my section acts header, in this tableview i also using paging to get the data from server.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (currentPage == 0) {
       return 1;

   }

    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
       return myObject.count+1;
    }

    return myObject.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
   return 1;

 }

 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection (NSInteger)section  

 {

    myTimeline = [myObject objectAtIndex:section];
    //the rest of my code to display text in UILabel cell, etc

 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (cell.tag == kLoadingCellTag) {
     currentPage++;
    [self getTimeline];
   }    
}
```

Now the problem is, I already make sure that my paging is working and myObject array count is increase.
But when i do the scroll it crash in method viewForHeaderInSection with reason "index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'" (i set the paging in in server with 10 items per page)

I think the section in ViewForHeaderInSection not updating with numberOfSectionsInTableView method that i already setup.

So how to make the section in ViewForHeaderInSection updated?

Thanks..

Comment: "i set the paging in in server with 10 items per page" - and does your server always have 10*k entries?

Answer (score 0):

Your `numberOfSectionsInTableview` has `return myObject.count+1;`, so the table view is dutifully asking for the header for the last section, which is beyond the bounds of your `myObject` array.  You need either to remove the `+1` or, if it's there for a reason, to include code in `viewForHeaderInSection` to handle that special case:

```
if (currentPage > 0 && currentPage < totalPages && section == myObject.count) {
    // create whatever header view is appropriate for the final section
} else {
    myTimeline = ... etc
}
```